# Trying to scrape text from pages where data are loaded from external URL

Tags: json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using this code to collect the links to all past minutes issued by the central bank of Brazil

```
import requests
import textwrap
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.bcb.gov.br/api/servico/sitebcb/atascopom-conteudo/ultimas?quantidade=1000&filtro="

data = requests.get(url).json()
links = []

for i in range(178):
    temp_link = "https://www.bcb.gov.br/"+data['conteudo'][i]['LinkPagina']
    links.append(temp_link)

print(links)
```

The code does generate all the links as needed. Unfortunately, when I loop over the links and try to copy the main text in the body of the respective pages, I get empty results. Based on a previous related question, I believe the issue is that the data in the respective pages are loaded from external URLs. Unfortunately I do not know how to overcome this problem in the context of my loop.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: which data you are looking to extract?

Comment: if are trying to extract data from `links` in which contents are dynamically loaded so `beautifulsoup` cant determine the output

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        params = {
            "quantidade": 1000,
            "filtro": ""
        }
        r = req.get(url, params=params)
        items = [x['LinkPagina'].rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
                 for x in r.json()['conteudo']]
        for x in items:
            npr = {
                "filtro": "IdentificadorUrl eq '{}'".format(x)
            }
            r = req.get(
                'https://www.bcb.gov.br/api/servico/sitebcb/atascopom/principal', params=npr)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(
                r.json()['conteudo'][0]['OutrasInformacoes'], 'lxml')
            print(soup.select_one('.lista1').text)
            exit() # <-- Remove it. 

main('https://www.bcb.gov.br/api/servico/sitebcb/atascopom-conteudo/ultimas')
```

Output:

```
1.
A
inflação medida pela variação do Índice Nacional de Preços ao Consumidor Amplo 
(IPCA) atingiu 0,78% em maio, 0,17 ponto percentual (p.p.) acima da registrada 
no mês anterior. Dessa forma, a inflação acumulada em doze meses registrou 9,32%
em maio (8,47% em maio de 2015), com os preços livres aumentando 8,82% (6,82%  
em maio de 2015), e os administrados, 10,90% (14,09% em maio de 2015).
Especificamente sobre preços livres, os de itens comercializáveis aumentaram 9,55%
em doze meses até maio (5,71% em maio de 2015), e os de não comercializáveis,  
8,19% (7,79% em maio de 2015). Note-se, ainda, que os preços no segmento de    
alimentação e bebidas variaram 12,72% em doze meses até maio (8,80% em maio de 
2015), e os dos serviços, 7,51% (8,23% em maio de 2015). Em síntese, as        
informações disponíveis refletem, em parte, a dinâmica de maior persistência   
dos preços no segmento de serviços – mas que já mostram alguma desaceleração –,os processos de realinhamento de preços relativos e choques temporários de     
oferta no segmento de alimentação e bebidas.
```

Comment: i think OP is able to generate the links but afterwards using these links there is some problem may be!

Comment: @BhavyaParikh Seems so, My Mistake. let's wait for the OP to describe which data he's trying to fetch.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. What I am trying to do is a loop over the  links to fetch the main text in each page. For instance, if you click in the link below you will see an example of the text (several paragraphs) I am trying to copy:                                    https://www.bcb.gov.br/publicacoes/atascopom/16072014

Comment: response = requests.get("https://www.bcb.gov.br/publicacoes/atascopom/16072014")
soup= BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser") 
minute = soup.find_all('div', class='lista1')

Comment: The code above does not give me the text I am looking for unfortunately

Comment: @TiagoS Kindly [edit] your question and limit it to specific thing! What exactly you are looking to extract.

Comment: This works great, except that it only copies the first paragraph in each minute. How can I copy the entire text instead?

Comment: @TiagoS `Stack Overflow!` is not code writing service, However please read [ask] and then provide [mcve]. also the answer provided for you is achieved your goal but looks like we are going from question to another one which is completely forbidden here. if you just print out `soup.prettify()` you will see the full `HTML` which you can parse it if you aware on how to use `bs4` parser.